# Converting $5\sin 60^\circ$ to $5\sqrt{3} / 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\eqalign{\dfrac x5&=\sin60^\circ \\ x&=5\sin60^\circ\\&=\dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

Can someone tell me how the last part was derived? How do I get from $5\sin 60^\circ$ to $5\sqrt{3} / 2$?

Comment: Becuase $\sin(60^{\circ}) = \sqrt 3 / 2$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Do I have to memorize that ?

Comment: It's a special triangle you should probably know.  Take an equilateral triangle and split it in half.

Comment: It's fairly useful to memorize [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#mediaviewer/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg) circle.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: draw a right triangle and note that the opposite side of  angle $30^\circ$ is half the length of the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**
draw an equilateral triangle, split it in half, and determine what the height is relative to the length of a side

[image]